# Laptop starts heating CPU while watching youtube video

Tags: drivers, video, overheating, youtube, temperature

I have an acer aspire 3 laptop, with an intel celeron n4000 @1.10 GHz, 8GB RAM and mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics 600 (GLK 2) with a X.Org foundation driver.

I buyed a blank ssd a month ago and installed ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS as the only OS on my laptop. Everything was running smoothly, my laptop became 10x faster, using multiple tabs on firefox, viewing pdfs, messaging on telegram, etc, and the temperature of the CPU never surpassed 40 °C.
One day, out of the blue while watching YT videos I noticed temperatures of +70°C and now the lowest temperature, with nothing open is around 40°C. Something strange is that if I'm on the YT tab watching the video the temperature raises, but if I change tabs and have the YT video on the background the temperature lowers to around 50°C.
This heating problem doesn't occur with videos I have downloaded. I already cleaned the dust inside and changed thermal paste. The fan works properly.

I know my laptop is very low-end but this situation came out of nowhere and wasn't normal a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: You should use the `top` command to find out whether the culprit is Firefox. And please close all unused tabs in Firefox. Unfocused Firefox tabs have a bug, where they use high CPU after Firefox restart.

Comment: How do I read the info that the command displays? Do you recommend another browser maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The heating problem you're facing is quite common with lower end processors I'm afraid. The reason for the heating is that internet browsers on Linux **do not** use hardware acceleration when playing videos whereas media players **do**. This is why the heating does not occur when you play downloaded videos. You play them with a media player, like `vlc` for example.

We all hope internet browsers will start using hardware acceleration some time soon, so that videos, especially the ones that use 50 or 60 fps, can play properly on lower end systems without overheating the cpu's.

Comment: It's very strange however that the problem wasn't there since the beginning. Do you think It can be due to malware or something like that?